# typehint class constructor with interface

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface

```
interface IDownloader {
    download()
}
```

and several classes implementing it:

```
class DownloaderA implements IDownloader {
...
}

class DownloaderB implements IDownloader {
...
}
```

Then I have a class that should receive constructors of the Downloader classes as parameters. I can do it when I specify a specific downloader like this:

```
class DownloadWorker {
    constructor(downloader: typeof DownloaderA) {
    }
}
```

but I cannot typehint an interface in the same way:

```
class DownloadWorker {
    constructor(downloader: typeof IDownloader) {
    }
}
```

How can I typehint the downloader argument so I can pass DownloaderA and DownloaderB constructors?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a constructor signature:

```
class DownloadWorker {
    constructor(downloader: new () => IDownloader) {
    }
}
```

The signature is similar to a function signature, but the `new` makes it callable with the `new` operator to create a new object.

The above code accepts a constructor (ie a class) with no parameters. you can add specific parameters, or define it as `new (...a:any[]) => IDownloader` to allow a constructor with any arguments.